# Cannot find files inside a directory in migration laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, migration

I'm writing a migration where it reads from the txt file and creates tables based on the data recieved from text file, the following works perfectly if i use it as a function

```
$files = File::glob("translation/*.txt" );
```

it gets all txt files inside /public/translation/ folder, but the above code is not working when i use it inside a migration file, can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such relative path is quite unreliable. Try using absolute path with these helpers http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths

Relative to `app_path()` should be good for you. For example

```
$files = File::glob(app_path()."/translation/*.txt" );
```